# How can I prevent cells in the "new" datagridview row from being selected if there are multiple datagridview rows selected?

Tags: c#, datagridview

Don't ask why, but I need a way to prevent the user from entering a cell in the 'new' datagridview row WHILE they've got multiple rows selected.

Currently, the cell in the first column of the row that the mouse is hovering over during the click and drag is being selected. If you click on the cell, then the rows aren't selected anymore, so you can't use any cell click events or anything.

Any suggestions are welcome.

P.S. don't try editing the currentcell from the selectionchanged event, already tried that!

Thanks,

Isaac

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea that the DataGridView control has a RowState property. When your row is selected, check the state. I'm not sure what the states are (if I'm even in the ballpark) ... anyway, you may be able to check that route.

I'm looking for more info ...

Okay ... think I found a decent way to do this:

```
void DataGridView1_RowsAdded (object sender, DataGridViewRowsAddedEventArgs e)
{
    currentNewRow = e.RowIndex;
}

void DataGridView1_CellMouseClick(Object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.RowIndex == currentNewRow)
    {
        // don't add to Selection
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, i should have been more specific in my question. The thing is when you select the multiple rows, it's actually selecting the first column's cell for the row that the mouse is on. So if you click and drag to select multiple rows and release, you still have a selected cell without actually clicking on it.

Answer (score 0):

Use CellStateChanged event:

```
private void dataGridView_CellStateChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellStateChangedEventArgs e) {
            if (e.Cell.OwningRow.IsNewRow && dataGridView.SelectedRows.Count > 1)
                e.Cell.Selected = false;
        }
```

Comment: Sorry, but cell state changed won't fire unless i click on the cell. But if i click on the cell, then the selected rows = 0.